# What is com_jce

Tags: plugins

Our firewall is actively blocking Wordpress attacks with posts to option=com_jce. Isn't com_jce Joomla thing? Does WordPress use references to Joomla?

Comment: No, core WordPress doesn't. But it's possible you have plugins that look for com_jce in the query string.

Comment: So these probably aren't genuine traffic, someone's just guessing you might be using Joomla and trying every exploit they know. So it sounds like your firewall is doing the right thing, unless you think this is genuine visitor traffic?

Comment: Say what you will about WordPress, it still has too much self-respect to associate with Joomla.